# Select region from an image but resizable QRubberBand doesn't resize

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to select a region from an image and get her coordinates. I have searched and I have found this code, it create object rubberband but I can't resize it.. weird, on linux (lubuntu) it's working but on macOS doesn't.. I want a version of a rubberband on macOS in special with those "grips", in macOS neither those grips doesn't appear.. and one more thing, it is possible to to move the rubberband rectangle by selecting with right click and move on image wherever I want, like moving an icon on desktop. Thanks!

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class ResizableRubberBand(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ResizableRubberBand, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.SubWindow)
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(
            QtWidgets.QSizeGrip(self), 0,
            QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft | QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        layout.addWidget(
            QtWidgets.QSizeGrip(self), 0,
            QtCore.Qt.AlignRight | QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom)
        self._band = QtWidgets.QRubberBand(
            QtWidgets.QRubberBand.Rectangle, self)
        self._band.show()
        self.show()

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        size = QtCore.QSize(3, 4)
        size.scale(self.size(), QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
        self.resize(size)
        self._band.resize(self.size())

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Show Rubber Band')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.handleButton)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.label.setScaledContents(True)
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap('image.JPG'))
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)

    def handleButton(self):
        self.band = ResizableRubberBand(self.label)
        self.band.setGeometry(50, 50, 150, 300)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(800, 100, 600, 500)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track. PyQt uses event handlers to control mouse interaction and resize events. For your application, resizing grips will call `resizeEvent` and repainting the changed window involves `paintEvent`. Similarly, mouse interaction utilizes `mousePressEvent`, `mouseMoveEvent`, and `mouseReleaseEvent` as event handlers are called when these actions are triggered. Essentially, for each interaction that you want, you must implement the handler for that particular event. I used PyQt4 to test but it should be the same for PyQt5.

[image]

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
# from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class ResizableRubberBand(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ResizableRubberBand, self).__init__(parent)

        self.draggable = True
        self.dragging_threshold = 5
        self.mousePressPos = None
        self.mouseMovePos = None
        self.borderRadius = 5

        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.SubWindow)
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(
            QtWidgets.QSizeGrip(self), 0,
            QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft | QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        layout.addWidget(
            QtWidgets.QSizeGrip(self), 0,
            QtCore.Qt.AlignRight | QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom)
        self._band = QtWidgets.QRubberBand(
            QtWidgets.QRubberBand.Rectangle, self)
        self._band.show()
        self.show()

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self._band.resize(self.size())

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        # Get current window size
        window_size = self.size()
        qp = QtWidgets.QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        qp.setRenderHint(QtWidgets.QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
        qp.drawRoundedRect(0, 0, window_size.width(), window_size.height(),
                           self.borderRadius, self.borderRadius)
        qp.end()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if self.draggable and event.button() == QtCore.Qt.RightButton:
            self.mousePressPos = event.globalPos()                # global
            self.mouseMovePos = event.globalPos() - self.pos()    # local
        super(ResizableRubberBand, self).mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.draggable and event.buttons() & QtCore.Qt.RightButton:
            globalPos = event.globalPos()
            moved = globalPos - self.mousePressPos
            if moved.manhattanLength() > self.dragging_threshold:
                # Move when user drag window more than dragging_threshold
                diff = globalPos - self.mouseMovePos
                self.move(diff)
                self.mouseMovePos = globalPos - self.pos()
        super(ResizableRubberBand, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if self.mousePressPos is not None:
            if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.RightButton:
                moved = event.globalPos() - self.mousePressPos
                if moved.manhattanLength() > self.dragging_threshold:
                    # Do not call click event or so on
                    event.ignore()
                self.mousePressPos = None
        super(ResizableRubberBand, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Show Rubber Band')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.handleButton)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.label.setScaledContents(True)
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap('image.JPG'))
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)

    def handleButton(self):
        self.band = ResizableRubberBand(self.label)
        self.band.setGeometry(150, 150, 150, 150)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(800, 100, 600, 500)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! I can move the rectangle but I can't resize it.. on linux I still manage.. simply I don't understand why

Comment: Look into PyQt resize flags. Maybe `QtWidgets.QSizeGrip` could vary between platforms.